# Apache Poi formula Strings

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

I have a strange behavious and hope that someone might know what is going on.

For a personal project in Java i'm using Apache poi (version 3.9) to read and write to excel files.
In these excel files there is a formula i wanted to change to another way writing it.

I have a loop that sets my Excelobject with the required formula string

excelobject.setDataFormula("SUM(L" + counter + "-6,75)"); // it will look like SUM(L2-6,75) and so on

However when i write these formula in a file and check it. it has mysteriously changed to something like SUM(L2-6;75). changing the , to a ; and thus the formula does not work like intended.

can someone explain to me why apache poi setFormula on a cell does this to a , ?

EDIT :

I changed my loop to use a double 6,75 instead of a string 6,75 and that seems to help when creating the formula. So this immediate question is fixed though I am still curious on why this behavious comes.

Comment: it looks like its because you are using a comma for your delimiter. did you try escape the comma in the string using \, ?

Comment: Yeah i tried an escape. but a \, is not a valid input for Strings :(

Comment: ok, i posted answer, reffering to the apachepoi javadocs might explain this in more detail.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go to `Control panel -> Region and Language -> Additional settings` and change the `List Separator` to something other than a comma. You should use a character that doesn't appear in your file. Be sure to pick something that won't be added to the file in future either.

It changes from `,` to `;` because `,` is being used as a delimiter. Anywhere that a `,` is found indicates a new cell. When your string is read, it changes the comma so that 2 cells wont be created where there should only be one. If you change the `List Separator` as described, the comma should remain unchanged.

Comment: Haha ok this is really weird. I went to check out this solution to see if it worked. My value was set on ; so it was allready not a , . Regardless I changed it to tilde (~) because that is something I never use. when i ran the formula changer again suddenly all ; where now tildes. making it 6~75. So it seems it uses this value indeed for some strange way. when i changed it to a comma to see what that did it made it ; again instead of a comma. So it seems to get that value for whatever it is when it is not a comma. but on a comma it makes it ; still. Its really vague. i will just doubles now.